# chartjs - How to use differente color if value is lower than previous value?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

On my web site I'm using chartjs for build beautifull line charts (like for documentation here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.2/charts/line.html)

I'm trying to find a solution to draw line charts in 2 color, in such a way that if the value is lower than the previous, then use color #2, so you can see very quickly if a value i goes down related to the previous data.

I'm exploring differents plugin, but no-one is doing exactly what I want.
The most close I found is the "Financial chart" plugin ( https://www.abelheinsbroek.nl/financial/ ), but I'd like my charts be normal line chart, not candle stick style like for that plugin.

Is there a plugin able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the wanted result by attributing the colors with a function on a gradientStroke.

Basically you can create a gradient line in Chart.js :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#f49080");
```

In the case above you would end up with a gradient from red (#80b6f4) to blue (#f49080) but you can simply divide 1 (position of the point) by the number of points you have.

For example, if you have 5 points you would do:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.25, "#f49080");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.5, "#f49080");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.75, "#80b6f4");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#f49080");
```

Create a function and use loops to make your solution scalable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I'm not a coder myself. My web site use dinamic value to popolate the chart, so I can't use your example.
How to make this as a rule, if next value is lower than previus, then use gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#80b6f4"); otherwise use gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#f49080"); ?

Thanks